# I cant use external Python libraries of Pandas, Numpy, BeautifulSoup and PyMongo in my Mule ESB application

Tags: python, mule, jython, esb

I need to use external Python libraries like Pandas, Numpy, BeautifulSoup and PyMongo in my Mule ESB application. I have modified the variable as below:

```
-Dpython.path=./lib/libPy/beautifulsoup4-4.8.1
```

However, with this environment variable the only thing I can achieve is to utilize one of the four libraries. Is there any other way to use these 4 libraries in the same Mule ESB application?

I have tried in the version used at the deployment, and using AnyPoint Studio controlling the VM arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use python.path with multiple paths by separating them with the OS separator char. For example for Linux/macOS is ':' and in Windows ';'.

Example:

```
-Dpython.path=/path/to/lib1:/path/to/lib2:/path/to/lib3
```